# Why does a linear fit to the data using SciDAVis gives a linear line lying away from data?

Tags: scidavis

A plot a graph with log(x) and Y. Now when I try to give a linear fit to the data, it strangely plots a straight line located far away from the data. Why did this happen?

[image]

Comment: Update it. If the issue persists, ask in the SciDaVis GitHub page instead.  https://github.com/highperformancecoder/scidavis